# Using the new Angular control flow syntax how can I conditionally wrap a span with anchor tag

Tags: angular

As the title suggests, I want to conditionally wrap a span with an anchor tag so it becomes a link. Below are some ways to get to the result, but I was wondering if there is a correct way.

This should be the result:
If the item has an url, the html will become

```
<a href="urltopage">
   <span>This is a message</span>
</a>
```

If the item doesn't have an url, html will become

```
<span>This is a message</span>
```

What I've come up with:

1.

```
@if (item.hasUrl()) {
<a [href]="item.url">
}
   <span>This is a message</span>
@if (item.hasUrl()) {
</a>
}
```

2. 

```
@if (item.hasUrl()) {
<a [href]="item.url">
   <span>This is a message</span>
</a>
} @else {
<span>This is a message</span>
}
```

Is there a correct way to achieve the result? I personally think #2 is a bit cleaner, but I still have a feeling it could be done nicer.

Answer (score 2):

For simple templates, it does not matter how you render your content but when it comes to complex scenarios, angular provides **ng-template** and **ng-container** to address such issues.

```html
    <ng-template #span>
       <span>Span Content</span>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #linkSpan>
      <a href=""> 
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="span"></ng-container> 
      </a>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="hasUrl() ? linkSpan : span">
    </ng-container>
```

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent {
 @Input() value!: string; 
}

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
  componentRef = SomeComponent;

  hasUrl() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**ng-container** is not limited to rendering **ng-template**, it can render components by reference.

```html
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="componentRef; inputs: { value: 'some value' }">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This is indeed a great way of doing it. While this works, I think using if and else (#2) is a bit more readable

Answer (score 0):

use this solution

I hope you get an answer

```
<a *ngIf="item.hasUrl(); else templateElese" [href]="item.url">
   <span>This is a message</span>
</a>

<ng-template #templateElese>
  <span>This is a message</span>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: As stated in the title, I'm searching for a solution using the new control flow